# window.location.hash does page reload?

Tags: javascript

OK so whenever I want to change my URL with hash, I do this:

`window.location.hash = 'something';`

But I have a question. Is it just me or does the page load again?

Comment: The page shouldn't reload. What browser/version are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript location.hash refreshing in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602260/javascript-location-hash-refreshing-in-ie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not reload, and if it does reload, then you might be using IE.

It appears to be a [***`bug`***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3286412/283863) in IE and you might want to try this:

```
window.location.hash = 'id';
```

This works on IE7. (Tried on IE9 using IE7 standard.)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal Didn't see it, sorry.