# IE makes extra GET-request on hash change

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, nginx, hashchange

When I make an XMLHttpRequest, I also change `window.location.hash`.

For example, `mysite.com/gallery/q#1` becomes `mysite.com/gallery/q#2`.

When this happens, IE8, as Fiddler and nginx logs show, makes this strange extra request to `mysite.com/gallery/` (which is 404).

The page isn't reloading, it's like an XMLHttpRequest.

```
GET http://mysite.com/gallery/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Referer: http://mysite.com/gallery/q
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: mysite.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Separately, hash change or Ajax-request won't trigger this extra one.

Another thing to note – the extra request occurs **not on every** Ajax-request. It happens seemingly randomly.

Can it be nginx misconfiguration? Or is it simply one of the many IE8 bugs?

Is there a workaround? I don't want this extra load.

---

#### Update

Here's the Ajax code (`$` stands for jQuery):

```
var id = link.getAttribute('data-id')

var xhr = $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    url: '/stock-items',
    method: 'GET',
    data: { id: id },
    dataType: 'json'
})
xhr.success(function (data) {
    if (currentId === id) {
        toggleLoader(false)
        displayData(data)
    }                                                                                                                           
})
```

And hash manipulating code:

```
function setHash(link) {
    var index = $(link).index()
    globals.location.hash = index + 1
}
```

Also tried with the hash-symbol with the same result:

```
globals.location.hash = '#' + index + 1
```

The Ajax-request is on click on gallery image links:

```
links.on('click', function (e) {
    setHash(this)                                                                                       
    loadData(this)
    e.preventDefault()
})
```

I also tried these `links` to have the `href` attribute set to `#1`, `#2` and so on in the HTML (and removed `e.preventDefault()`). So that the hash changes naturally. Nope, the extra request is made anyway.

Comment: What's the exact JavaScript you're using to change the hash?

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT-, added the code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the visitor being redirected to the affected page from another? If so, it's likely to be a known IE bug.

Take a look at this similar question: [javascript location.hash refreshing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602260/javascript-location-hash-refreshing-in-ie)

Comment: Greg, yes, I've seen this question. It's not a redirect, and solutions provided in the answers to that question don't work for my case (I checked).

Comment: Is the site live now? Can you share the path to the affected page?

Comment: Greg, it's not live yet. I can share the code, though. See the updated question soon.