# change window.location.hash without reloading page / website

Tags: javascript, hash

which browsers still do a page refresh if the location hash changes and which not?
Do the current browsers not reload the website?

need to change the hash using window.location.hash without reloading the website

Comment: hash changes don't move the page. what makes you say that?

Comment: saw this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602260/javascript-location-hash-refreshing-in-ie and somehwere that it refreshes in some browsers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No browsers should cause a page reload with the hash changing.