# AngularJS redirectTo fails on IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

I've got a router like that

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
             redirectTo: function(){
              return '/mdp';
             }
         })
         .when('/mdp', {
             templateUrl: 'views/mdp/dashboard.html'
         })
         .when('/mdg', {
             templateUrl: 'views/mdg/dashboard.html'
         })
         .otherwise({
             templateUrl: '/views/error/404.html'
         });
});
```

It works pretty well but when i'm on `IE8` I've got a strange bug !

I set the url : localhost:9000 in my browser nav bar and it's ok `IE8` redirect to :

```
localhost:9000/#/mdp
```

But after if I change the url in the navbar and I set :

```
localhost:9000/#/mdg
```

and I type on the enter key of the keyboard nothing happens, I have to hit `CTRL+F5`,

I don't understand really

Answer (score 0):

Without the hashtag, the browser will do a normal HTTP GET request to the server, and the request obviously wont find anything at `localhost:9000/mdp`

The hashtag is purposefully excluded from the HTTP request, because `"it is used to delimit a URI from a fragment identifier in URI references"`  This is useful for javascript routing that utilizes hashtags, and other logic used to maintain the state of the page.

So, simply changing the hashtag should not cause the browser to make another request for the page.

There is some related info in this post that may be helpful to you:
[javascript location.hash refreshing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602260/javascript-location-hash-refreshing-in-ie)