# Angular js IE reloads page after hash change

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3, hash

I was working on angular js implementation in ASP.NET MVC3 application.

I have loaded my products using

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
        // Initiates the AJAX call
        $http({ method: 'Get', url: scope.url ,params: {categoryId: scope.categoryId,pageIndex:scope.pageIndex,brandId:scope.brandString,orderBy:scope.orderBy} }).success(deferred.resolve).error(deferred.reject);
        // Returns the promise - Contains result once request completes
        return deferred.promise;
```

Everything is happening properly. After getting products I am updating my url hash so that page is identified by hash parameters. Somehow after updating hash IE is reloading my page and removed hash tag from my url.

I am changing the hash as

```
location.hash = 'pagenumber=' + ($scope.pageIndex+1) + ',orderby=' + $scope.orderBy + ',brandid=' + $scope.brandString;
```

My url looks like

```
mysite.net/#/pagenumber=1,orderby=20,brandid=8:104
```

Anybody knows workaround for this.

Comment: how do you update the hash tag, please add this code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602260/javascript-location-hash-refreshing-in-ie

Comment: Cant get u , which solutions should i use from that link.

Comment: as it seams from their answers it is a bug in IE, but don't know if there a work around.

Comment: why are you updating `location.hash` in an angular app?

Comment: If any use shares url with other user with applied filetrs. These filters should be used on next request.

Comment: It looks like you'll need to supply a href not a has as per this comment http://stackoverflow.com/a/2824127/523496