# Suppress navigation when setting HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark property in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, navigation

I have a scenario where I need to change the HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark property, but I want to do it without causing the Silverlight application to reload.  Right now, I'm doing this, but it's causing the application to restart:

```
public void SetBookmark(string authenticationGroupTag, string ownerUserTag, string roomName)
{
    string bookmark = GetBookmark(authenticationGroupTag, ownerUserTag, roomName);
    HtmlPage.Window.CurrentBookmark = bookmark;
    // HtmlPage.Window.Eval("window.location.hash='" + bookmark + "'");
}
```

That particular behavior -- restarting the application -- doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, so I wonder if I'm just doing it wrong.  I've tried catching various navigation related events (either Page.OnNavigatedFrom or RootFrame.Navigating), but neither of those actually get fired: the app just unloads and then reloads.

So I guess I have two parts to my question: (1) Is this the expected behavior, or am I just doing something wrong? and (2) If it *is* the expected behavior, has anyone come up with a workaround for it? Is there a way to update the portion of the URL after the "#" without reloading the Silverlight application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is just a variant of a problem that's been long noted, namely, that Internet Explorer refreshes the page when (a) the user has arrived at the current page after a redirect, and (b) you change the window.location.hash.  In other words, this is an IE issue (still not fixed in IE9!), not a Silverlight problem.  Everything behaves correctly with Firefox and Chrome.  (See [javascript location.hash refreshing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602260/javascript-location-hash-refreshing-in-ie) and [Response.Redirect with a fragment identifier causes unexpected refresh when later using location.hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985056/response-redirect-with-a-fragment-identifier-causes-unexpected-refresh-when-later) for more details, and some suggested workarounds.)